# CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED after sleep windows10

Tags: windows-10, bsod, sleep

Everytime after sleep my windows crashes, sometimes it throws `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED`, sometimes `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`, sometimes `UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION`. I have tried using `chkdsk`, `sfc`, MEMORYDIAGNOSTICS none of which resulted in any error. I have also updated all the drivers recommended by the windows in the windows update (I updated it after the error started to show up)

I tried to boot in safe mode but I couldn't reproduce the problem as the PC won't go to sleep in safe mode.

After some debugging I found out that it had something to do with `ntoskrnl.exe`.

Here is the dump data:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED (ef)
        A critical system process died
Arguments:
Arg1: ffff82864f995080, Process object or thread object
Arg2: 0000000000000000, If this is 0, a process died. If this is 1, a thread died.
Arg3: 0000000000000000, The process object that initiated the termination.
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 5624

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 24616

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 406

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 2832

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 85

    Key  : CriticalProcessDied.ExceptionCode
    Value: 4e004080

    Key  : CriticalProcessDied.Process
    Value: services.exe

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


FILE_IN_CAB:  031122-56750-01.dmp

BUGCHECK_CODE:  ef

BUGCHECK_P1: ffff82864f995080

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  services.exe

CRITICAL_PROCESS:  services.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x4e004080 - <Unable to get error code text>

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffeb08`83395838 fffff801`261086d2     : 00000000`000000ef ffff8286`4f995080 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffeb08`83395840 fffff801`2600fceb     : 00000000`00000000 fffff801`25afd8ad 00000000`00000002 fffff801`25afcec7 : nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x10e
ffffeb08`833958e0 fffff801`25eb58b4     : ffff8286`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8286`4f995080 ffff8286`4f9954b8 : nt!PspTerminateAllThreads+0x15ab6f
ffffeb08`83395950 fffff801`25eb5bdc     : ffff8286`4f995080 00000000`00000000 00000067`0e14f5fc 0000016c`29730000 : nt!PspTerminateProcess+0xe0
ffffeb08`83395990 fffff801`25c08fb5     : ffff8286`4f995080 ffff8286`4e004080 ffffeb08`83395a80 ffffeb08`83395a80 : nt!NtTerminateProcess+0x9c
ffffeb08`83395a00 00007ffb`d4f2d2f4     : 00007ffb`d4fa2c03 00007ffb`d4fd66f8 00000067`0e14f5c0 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
00000067`0e14cb28 00007ffb`d4fa2c03     : 00007ffb`d4fd66f8 00000067`0e14f5c0 00000000`00000000 00007ffb`d4e90000 : 0x00007ffb`d4f2d2f4
00000067`0e14cb30 00007ffb`d4fd66f8     : 00000067`0e14f5c0 00000000`00000000 00007ffb`d4e90000 00000000`00000004 : 0x00007ffb`d4fa2c03
00000067`0e14cb38 00000067`0e14f5c0     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffb`d4e90000 00000000`00000004 00007ffb`d4f352ed : 0x00007ffb`d4fd66f8
00000067`0e14cb40 00000000`00000000     : 00007ffb`d4e90000 00000000`00000004 00007ffb`d4f352ed 00007ffb`d4fd66f8 : 0x00000067`0e14f5c0


SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+10e

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1586

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  10e

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xEF_services.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_4e004080_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {80488985-3d37-d26f-c5e9-d016e3866e8a}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

If you need anymore details let me know.

Comment: What memory test did you use? The built-in Windows test? Did you run it in extended mode for a long enough time period? What's your OS drive, HDD or SSD? Did you use `dism` to check your Windows yet?

Comment: @DanielB Thank you for the reply. Yes I used the inbuilt windows memory test. I am using HDD and yes I did use dism. I am not sure what extended mode is, is it extending the windows to multiple monitors? If so no, as I don't have multiple monitors

Comment: No, I am referring to the memory test. By default, it runs only a very basic test that may not pick up all errors. // Also, you should check the System log in Event Viewer for errors, especially disk errors.

Comment: @DanielB I had run MemoryDiagnostic inbuilt tool it prompted me to restart after which it did a thorough check and there was no error found.